# React Router v4 - How to prevent redirect loops?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have my `App` component redirect to the "/login" route if the state's uid is null. The redirect works correctly and will always redirect you to "/login" if there is a null uid, however the problem is it doesn't stop redirecting once you're on the "/login" route.

The error being thrown is:

*Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/login"*

One last constraint is I need the uid to be null until after a login event fires from the `LoginScreen` component. So the user needs to be able to view the "/login" route with a null uid in the top-level `App` component.

My code is as follows:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      uid: null
    }
  }
  render() {
    // Redirect to login if no user
    if (this.state.uid == null) {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        </Router>
      );
    }

    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardScreen} />
          <Route path="/profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope I explained the situation well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Well as you mention that you have store the uid in the `App` component state and you are redirecting to the Login component if the `uid` is not present. However there is a technical fault here.

The state of the component is initilised everytime the component is mounted again and when you redirect from the Login component to the App component, your state in App component is again initialized to null which is why you are redirected again to Login.

What you need to do is to

**Either** store the uid in localStorage and read it from there in the App component

**Or**  if you are using `Redux`, then store the `uid` in global store and `fetch` it in the App component.

Answer (score 1):

Its because when it redirects to /login it goes from '/' i.e App component and render function calls again which indeed redirects to /login and goes in the loop so on. 
So instead to prevent this update the state in login component and pass it to the parent component.

So if you are not using any store like redux, just set the state in the window.localStorage.