# How to user React router redirect correctly ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, redux, react-router

I have stuck with one problem.
When I want to do Redirect I receive this error 
**`You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/"`** 
My **App.js** file looks like this

```js
render() {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    if (!auth.isAuthentificated) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
      
    return (
      ...
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/welcome" component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="/user-info" component={UserInfo} />
        <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
```

If my code was not clear for you - help me with any advice. How I can redirect users from any Routs to `LoginPage` component if `!auth.isAuthentificated === true` 
I am using `react-router 4.2.0,`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345391/react-router-v4-how-to-prevent-redirect-loops?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to verify that you are not *already* at that path before you redirect to it:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

// ...

render() {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    const {pathname} = this.props.location;

    if (!auth.isAuthentificated && pathName !== '/') {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }

    return (
        ...
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/welcome" component={Welcome} />
            <Route path="/user-info" component={UserInfo} />
            <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} />
        </Switch>
    );
}
```